# BigQuery Python 409 Already Exists: Table

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm coding a python script that writes query results to a BQ table . After the first time running the script, it always errors out after that with the following error: `google.api_core.exceptions.Conflict: 409 Already Exists: Table project-id.dataset-id`. I do not understand why it is attempting to create a table everytime I run the script. Do I have specify any specific parameters?

This is from the documentation from google. I'm using this as an example and under the idea that a current table has already been created. Where do I stop the api from creating the same table ?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# TODO(developer): Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the destination table.
 table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id)

sql = """
    SELECT corpus
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
    GROUP BY corpus;
"""

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
query_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you check the class [QueryJobConfig](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html) you will see that there is a parameter called `write_disposition`. As you can see in the REST API reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery.FIELDS.write_disposition), this parameter can be set to 3 different options:

- `WRITE_TRUNCATE`: If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the table data and uses the schema from the query result.
- `WRITE_APPEND`: If the table already exists, BigQuery appends the data to the table.
- `WRITE_EMPTY`: If the table already exists and contains data, a 'duplicate' error is returned in the job result.

So, adding this line after the `job_config` definiton will do the trick:

```
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
```

Answer (score 0):

look into this BigQuery client documentation [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html) look into exists_ok parameter