# Bigquery Job ID already exists

Tags: python, php, google-bigquery

We have been running many jobs in BigQuery via the Python library before. Recently we also have been using the PHP library to do some streaming inserts. Since then we have conflicts with job id's and we cannot set the id's ourselves. The error happens on both sides PHP and Python and happens at seemingly random queries. The error looks like this:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Conflict: 409 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{project}/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Already Exists: Job {project}:US.{job_id}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836940/bigquery-python-409-already-exists-table) solve your problem?

Comment: No, I don’t have the issue that the table exists, I have the issue that the job_id already exists. It seems like a google internal bug when using the python and php library at the same time…

Comment: The error [`Already Exists: Job`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages) occurs when the server finds it already has a job with the same id.In some cases, the API client or HTTP client might not receive the confirmation that the job is inserted due to transient issues or network interruptions. When the insertion is retried, that request will fail with status=ALREADY_EXISTS . If you have a support plan,  I would recommend you to raise a ticket with Google Cloud Support. If not, you can raise a ticket in [Google’s Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).